# Laravel 5.2 TokenMisMatchException on Production Server

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am encountering TokenMismatchException on my Production Server, but the application working fine on local Xampp server and another hosting. It our in house server, so we cannot changed it. We have to use it, but we did not understand where is the issue.

Please friends help me, did i need to change anything in server like plugin, extensions or anything else, Please let me know. Here is screen shot below:

[image: Error on production when submitting login blank and geeting token mismatchexception]

[image: This on my personal hosting and the same is working fine here.]

Above sceenshot is from Production and one of hosting provider. On production server laravel application giving tokenmismatchexception whereas same application working fine on another hosting provider. We did not understand why this is happening. Please suggest us what to do.

**Update:**

I have fresh laravel 5.2 and run `php artisan make:auth` after that i have given 777 permission to the folder, then donw nothing. Still i am getting this exception.

Comment: Is the production server load balanced?

Comment: I think so. I have not configured the server. It is already configure by engineer.

Comment: If the server is load balanced and you are storing sessions in the file system then you will get issues posting forms. I have experienced this on production Laravel sites. Check the post and get information when you submit forms if the IP is different then you'll be experiencing the issue I mentioned. Solution are Redis or similar to handle the sessions and persist across variations in IP

Comment: I have also use database for session, but still i am getting same issue.

Comment: If you've set an APP URL in the `.env` file then this may also be playing a part in the issue

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your html form

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

in blade

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```

And add your route in web middwlware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
      // Place all your web routes here...
});
```

Comment: I am using Html Collective anf doing {{ Form::open() }} which will add token hidden field automatically. If this will be the issue then why application working on another hosting. I think problem is related to server, not from application.

Comment: I have already added {{ csrf_field() }} this line to my form and it is generating token hidden field too.

Comment: I really don't get why people are upping this when the dev is clearly stating it's not fixed. CSRF toke on a form isn't the only reason this happens!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the sessions that are not being set properly.
Try to delete your **PHP_SESSID cookie** or change the way the sessions are stored on the server.

You can also check if sessions are working properly with a testing route.

Comment: how to delete PHP_SESSID cookie

Comment: @Mandy : If you're using Firefox, it's in `Preferences > Privacy`. I don't know for other browsers

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, for me the problem was

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=custom_domain_here
```

Setting in my .env file, which was different between production and local. This will cause the sessions to be created incorrectly for the domain and throw a TokenMismatch.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you have to create token in your configuration file.

Try either built in artisan command `$ php artisan key:generate` or create the key manually.

Comment: This is also not working. Key was generated like : Application key [base64:some key=] set successfully.

Comment: Then create it manually in config/app.php. I think it is supposed to be 32 characters in length. Any string.

Comment: Also make sure you have proper variable in ENV file.

Comment: Yes it 32 char in length and i am using .env file too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing something wrong with user login. Recently I was facing the same problem. In my case the problem that I was using `Auth::login($user,true)` instead of `Auth::login($user)` or `Auth::attempt...`

Secondly you also should check out if you have **remember_token** column in your user's database.

Thirdly you need to check where your session is stored.

I hope it will help!

Comment: Currently i did not do anything own, i am using laravel scaffolding. so whatever you have said total not possible in my case. currently i am using database for session, but earlier i was using file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('laravel-master/login') }}">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ session()->getToken() }}">
```

This line in my form view.

Comment: try the updated answer. please make sure your URL is same as `{{ url('laravel-master/login') }}`

Comment: This is also not working. it also added laravel-master twice.

Answer (score 0):

try to verify your Session file => App/Config
'domain' => 'ip adresse or Domaine name',
and if the domaine name has SSl certification
change the secure variable to True 
i hope it will help you :D